# PythonAnywhere module not found

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

I set up a task on PythonAnywhere to run a file every day however when it came time to run it, it said that "No module named pyowm.owm". However when I run the finally normally in the file section of PythonAnywhere it runs perfectly fine. I've tried installing the modules for both Python 3.7 and 3.8 however neither have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify Python executable for the script either by adding a shebang `#!/usr/bin/python3.8` at the beginning of the script or by defining the scheduled task's command like: `python3.8 /home/myusername/myproject/myscript.py` (examples are for Python 3.8). You may use a virtualenv as well, in such case the command should look like: `/home/myusername/.virtualenvs/myvenv/bin/python /home/myusername/myproject/mytask.py`.